# Django rendering Template tags on HTML Webpage in text

Tags: python, django, templates, for-loop

My django HTML tags don't work when running them through a "for" loop. If I print out the variable it prints the plain list out.I even tried different ways of assigning the variable. What's happening?

**view.py**

```
class CheckbackView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        statusly = request.POST.get("ConfigSubmit", "")
        list_init_config = statusly.splitlines()
        with open('/data/test.txt', 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(statusly)
            fout.close()
        converted = Con1812_to_891(statusly)
        converted_config = converted.config
        removed_list = converted.remove_list

        return render(request, 'thunderdome/compare_edit.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request, {'config': statusly, 'converted': converted.config, 'removed': removed_list, 'objection': converted}))
```

**Renders like this:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
{ % for line in removed %}
    <li>{{ line|safe }}</li>
{ % endfor %}



{ % for line in objection.remove_list %}
    <li>{{ line }}</li>
{ % endfor %}

{{objection.remove_list}}

{{removed}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax in your template is a little off; remove the spaces between the `{` and the `%`:

```
{% for line in removed %}
    <li>{{ line|safe }}</li>
{% endfor %}



{% for line in objection.remove_list %}
    <li>{{ line }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I should have known Django would be so picky about template tags.

Comment: In that scope, python or any programming language is also picky, because you can't use loop instead of for.